# how to get a list of all user friends?

Tags: csv, facebook-graph-api, export-to-csv, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, facebook-friends

I am building an app using *Facebook Graph API v.20*.

The first thing it needs to do is to export the complete list of friends from the user (`ID, name and picture`) to a CSV file.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph Api v2.0 me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-use-m)

Answer (score 4):

### Short answer: No.

The [Graph API v2.0 reference documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friends) implies that your app will only be able to access (through the API, at least) those of the user's friends who have themselves used your app **and** allowed your app to access their own friends list:

> **Permissions**
>
> - A user access token with `user_friends` permission is required to view the current person's friends.
> - This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request.
> - If a friend of the person declines the `user_friends` permission, that friend will not show up in the friend list for this person.

@user664833 pointed out some clarifications to the policy in the comment below:

> Effective *April 30th, 2014* for Facebook's API v2.0: (1) **Friend list is no longer part of the default permission set and has its own permission**: Asking for access to a person's friend list is now a separate permission that your app must request. The new permission is called user_friends. (2) **Friend list now only returns friends who also use your app**: The list of friends returned via the /me/friends endpoint is now limited to the list of friends that have authorized your app. [developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) -- URL accessible by FB users registered as developers –  user664833 Jun 10 at 5:50

Actually, the URL seems to be public, since I can view it while not logged in. The changelog also explains why some apps can still view *all* friends, as @SimonCross pointed out:

> For apps that existed before April 30th 2014, making an API call without specifying a version number ('unversioned') is equivalent to making a call to the v1.0 of the API.
>
> For apps created on or after April 30th 2014, making an API call without a specifing a version number is equivalent to making a call to v2.0 of the API.
>
> Apps that were inactive or have a creation date on or after April 30th, 2014 will not be able to make calls to v1.0 of the API. They must use v2.0.

Comment: I see an application that can do this, it's called friendlistexporter https://apps.facebook.com/friendlistexporter   What workaround do they use to bypass this new rule you implemented?

Comment: I did not implement any rule. This is not a Facebook support site. I'm not sure how that app was implemented, but you could try asking its creator via [the contact links on his website](http://www.amagit.com/).

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to acquire the facebook friend list of a user, with other tools different than the graph API V2.0 ?

Comment: @camilo No, I do not know.

Comment: friendlistexporter was likely created before April 30th 2014 and this can still call Graph API v1.0 until April 20th 2015 - this is why they are, for now, able to acquire the full friend list of a user. 

Apps created after April 30th 2014 may only call Graph API v2.0. In API v2.0, the API returns only the subset of a user's friends who have also logged into the app.

Comment: Effective *April 30th, 2014* for Facebook's API v2.0: (1) **Friend list is no longer part of the default permission set and has its own permission**: Asking for access to a person's friend list is now a separate permission that your app must request. The new permission is called user_friends. (2) **Friend list now only returns friends who also use your app**: The list of friends returned via the /me/friends endpoint is now limited to the list of friends that have authorized your app. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog -- URL accessible by FB users registered as developers

Comment: I also saw that, any workround to get the whole friends list?

Comment: @Stony If your app was created before 4/30/2014, you might still be able to get it by calling the 1.0 API, as Simon indicated. Aside from that, I am not aware of any workaround.